# Deploying library to Clojars, get 405

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to deploy a lein project to Clojars:

```
$ lein deploy clojars
Copying 32 files to /home/chris/IdeaProjects/default-db-format/lib
No namespaces to :aot compile listed in project.clj.
Created /home/chris/IdeaProjects/default-db-format/default-db-format-0.1.0.jar
Wrote pom.xml
Deploying to http://clojars.org/repo/
Uploading: default-db-format/default-db-format/0.1.0/default-db-format-0.1.0.jar to repository clojars at http://clojars.org/repo/
Transferring 13K from clojars
An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Error deploying artifact 'default-db-format:default-db-format:jar':   Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://clojars.org/repo/default-db-format/default-db-format/0.1.0/default-db-format-0.1.0.jar. Return code is: 405
```

This seems like an error coming from Maven. I'm guessing I need to go through the steps [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/preview/doc/DEPLOY.md#deploying-to-maven-central), but am unsure.

Can someone who's done this before guide me on what to do next? There's documentation on the Internet but I've found nothing saying 'when you hit a 405, this is what you do next...'

Perhaps the jar has been deployed to Clojars, and thus the error can be ignored??

I didn't need to specify any PGP certificates, which I expected to be asked about. Perhaps there's no need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the Linux package manager's version of lein which was very old (`lein -version` gave 1.7.1). I needed to uninstall it (`dpkg --remove leiningen`) and install it manually. The [instructions](http://leiningen.org/#install) at the Leiningen site worked perfectly for this. I just cut and pasted into a file called lein, chmod etc...

The error messages I now get are about PGP issues, as expected...